# Is there an abstract theory of functions?

Tags: functions, axioms

Is there any good way to explain formally what functions are?

What I mean is that the understanding is usually rooted in set theory, saying that a function from a domain set to a codomain set is a certain kind of subset of their Cartesian product set.
This just seems to be a kind of example of a function though, in the same way that a Dedekind cut or an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers are examples of real numbers within set theory. In that case I can check that the set of each such structure has the correct properties of the axiomatically defined real ordered field when the appropriate arithmetic and order relation are added.

I wonder if we can explain exactly what functions have to look like, other than by explaining it in everyday language, so that we can prove that the "model" of functions that resides in set theory indeed satisfies the desired axiomatic properties.

Comment: would category theory count? Or maybe topos theory?

Comment: IMO "a function is a binary relation over two sets that associates every element of the first set, to exactly one element of the second set" completely defines a function. What more do you want ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)

Comment: It's part of the set theory, typically. It's a necessary tool for [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality).

Comment: Words "good way" are very subjective - imho, first 2 lines under your question is the most good understanding.

Comment: @Angina Seng: I only take Set Theory as an example, since it is the one that I know. If I knew anything about what functions are in Universal Algebra, I could have taken that as an example instead. What I mean by "good" is having a separate theory which is independent of the language of any other theory. Arithmetic has such theories.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: yes I agree on how to define a function in the language of sets. And I agree that the definition is reasonable. Maybe because I have once seen an illustration of group of children each of whom gets to pick one apple from a basket, and I have been told that this is what a function should do. Or because I know how to program a function in a language such as C++. The examples all illustrate how a function ought to behave. What I am missing is that the notion doesn't seem strictly formal.

Comment: @TommyR.Jensen: what is informal in "a relation" ? And in "exactly one element" ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust: concerning "a relation" there are two possibilities. Either you make conversation strictly in a specific language, say, the language of set theory. In this case the notion of relation has an agreed upon formal meaning. Or you mention the concept in general terms, with no reference to any given formal language. It is in the latter case that I do not see how it can a priori be a formal concept.

Comment: @TommyR.Jensen: obviously first interpretation. "Exactly" is "one and only one", like in $\exists !$".

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in ETCS, the '[Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS)'. It's a theory of sets, but it doesn't use membership as a fundamental concept. Instead it uses functions. Functions aren't defined as a subset of the cartesian product, they're simply taken to be fundamental objects. Then there are axioms describing how functions behave and what their properties are, and everything else is built up from that.